# Need help in typecasting string in to int

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I am using `Convert.ToInt32(ddlBuyer1Country.SelectedValue)`; to typecast a string returned by selectedvalue.
But this is giving me 0 instead of 3. I have selected value as 3 in this case.

Comment: Please verify where you are handling this, be it in Page_Init, Page_Load, or a postback event. Also, what is the format for the selected value string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `Int.TryParse(ddlBuyer1Country.SelectedValue, out myInt);`

But double check to make sure that you are not re-binding the dropdown on postback, that could reset your selected value to 0.  Make sure the dropdown bind only occurs in a:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) will return a 0, if the value is null.

Are you sure SelectedValue is not null before calling Convert?

How are you using the ddlBuyer1Country?